# How to add javascript to YII correctly?

Tags: yii

I want to create several javascript function that will be needed on different pages. Most will be relevant only to one page, but some to several. I know if I add general conversion functions, it would be a good idea to just create a new javascript file and put all these generic functions into that one file. Bringing me to my first question:

- Where would you store the generic javascript file? In "protected"? Which subfolder?

Then, I need to address the placement of other javascript code.

- If I have javascript that will only be used on one page, should I use [this technique](http://www.techportal.co.za/yii-framework/439-how-to-add-javascript-to-you-view-files-using-the-yii-framework) or should I stick to a similar approach as above?

The emphasis is on doing it correctly. I want to fall exactly in line with the yii framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store your generic javascript file in your_app/js folder
i.e js folder is at same level to protected. 
if js is only used on one page than it will be better not to use generic file.

Comment: I actually ended up doing this --> http://weavora.com/blog/2011/11/24/yii-framework-an-easy-was-to-split-javascript-from-html/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to have you generic js code into `/js/` or similar named folder under root of your app code. Personally I would separate my custom code files into one other subdirectory `/js/custom/` and `/js/vendors/` where in this vendor folder you can put ready js code such as jquery plugins etc.

Also don't forget to set this path to config file like this:

```
'components'=>array(

   'clientScript' => array(

      'coreScriptUrl' => 'path/to/js/lib/dir',

      'enableJavaScript' => true,

   ),

),
```

where `path/to/js/lib/dir` is your final js folder name path